# Python cryptography Fernet.generate_key() key length

Tags: python, python-3.x, cryptography, python-cryptography

I don't know much about cryptography but when I used cryptography library in python and tried generating a key, the key length was above 32

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
import base64

key = Fernet.generate_key()
>>>x2pXHXqCcUGjcq4HTcvdqH5xSEF_SLATO6p1Xk3tejM=
```

If I use this key to decrypt a message **online** or outside python, it would say key's max length is 32
I read that cryptography library uses 128 bit key CBC AES.

I'm not sure if this is something related to padding, my question is it possible to decrypt Fernet-encrypted messages outside python using this key or is there anyway I can get the original 16 bytes key (since it should be using 128 key)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key generated by `Fernet.generate_key()` and expected by the constructor actually consists of two 128-bit keys: one for signing, and the other is for encryption, concatenated in that order.

From the [source code](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/blob/master/src/cryptography/fernet.py):

```
    key = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(key)
    if len(key) != 32:
        raise ValueError(
            "Fernet key must be 32 url-safe base64-encoded bytes."
        )

    self._signing_key = key[:16]
    self._encryption_key = key[16:]
```

*Update thanks to @PaulKehrer*

This is described in the [format specification](https://github.com/fernet/spec/blob/master/Spec.md#key-format), quoting below:

A fernet *key* is the base64url encoding of the following fields:

```
Signing-key ‖ Encryption-key
```

- Signing-key, 128 bits
- Encryption-key, 128 bits

Using low-level libraries and services to decrypt Fernet messages requires parsing the [token format](https://github.com/fernet/spec/blob/master/Spec.md#token-format) manually:

- Fernet produces url-safe base64
- Besides data, the token contains version, timestamp, IV and HMAC

Comment: The [spec](https://github.com/fernet/spec/blob/master/Spec.md#key-format) explicitly documents this key format actually.

Comment: Hi, i still face issues with input length (The decrypted message) it says "Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher"

sites like [link](https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/aes-encryption-decryption)

**example: fernet key:** b'pZoloqJuKowAd3JsAtecK5ZkGpx4vaxIwyFU3TWTWzE='

**encrypted:** b'gAAAAABgHcCJe6tuM-a2aMY8eah35eY2GzhVcOl4zi0wgQ8EGcP-V4f7ItIBbs8JHpins1TzDO32DaUTDA-xms_1WEM5tRdX0A=='

Comment: @anewuser there are few problems with using a third-party service. First, fernet produces a [url-safe base64](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.urlsafe_b64encode), which can be rejected by other libraries. Second, you're still passing the entire 32-bytes fernet key, where 16-bytes key is expected. Finally, the output of Fernet encryption, besides ciphertext, contains version, timestamp, IV, and HMAC (see [spec](https://github.com/fernet/spec/blob/master/Spec.md#token-format)).